# stop words removal in java

Tags: java, stop-words

i wonder if there is any clue how to kick off to write my own stop words removal, while i dont wanna use any external libraries.after creating the HashSet, how could we put it into work to remove the stop words of a text?once again, i dont want to use any external libraries.

Comment: Do you need something like [this]?(http://www.textfixer.com/resources/common-english-words.txt)

Comment: You could read the stop words from a file or ressource.

Comment: I don't quite get what your question is: do you want to somehow calculate what the stopwords are or do you need a faster way of adding those that you define to the set?

Comment: Could you elaborate your question. It is hard to find out what you try to achieve.

Comment: well, i want to write a function to remove stop words, first needed to make a list of them, so now after it what should i do next?

Comment: Where do you want to remove the stop words from? Your goals are still quite vague.

Answer (score 2):

I would read them from a file. One line per word.

```
Set<String> stopWords = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("stop-words.txt"));
for(String line;(line = br.readLine()) != null;)
   stopWords.add(line.trim());
br.close();

if(stopWords.contains(word))
   // it's a stop word
else
   // it's not a stop word.
```

Comment: +1 Using the link @chance provided you'd have them in one line and need to split them using `,` as the separator. But that's just another format of the file's content :)

Comment: so after creating such a HashSet, how to put it into work?

Comment: @MostafaAlli I have added an example of using the set.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a set of stop words and a list of words you want to remove the stop words from, just iterate over the list and remove any words that are contained in the stop words set:

```
Set<String> stopWords = new HashSet<String>(  );
//fill stopWords

//use a linked list to make removal faster, you don't need random access here
List<String> text = new LinkedList<String>(  ); 
//fill text

Iterator<String> textIterator = text.iterator();
while( textIterator.hasNext() ) {
  //this assumes there are no null entries in the list       
  //and all stopwords are stored in lower case
  if( stopWords.contains( textIterator.next().toLowerCase() )) {
    textIterator.remove();
  }
}
```

Comment: yeay! that looks like what i meant :)

Answer (score 0):

Well the general idea of how you do stop word removal is that you split the input text into words and then do a lookup of each word in the stopword map.  The stopword lookup probably needs to be case-insensitive.

Details will vary depending on what the text is and what you are going to do with it.

Comment: i know , but when we found the stop word, how to take it out from text?

Comment: @MostafaAlli - you take it out of the text by not including it when you put the text back together from the words.  See my answer.